# get id and image from mysql database and use it in android apps

Tags: php, android

i create a table in `Mysql` database : Person(id int, Image blob).

i create a `Php` script which allows me to display the image in the browser, i took the URL of this `php` script and use it in android apps to show the image in an `Imageview`. but now i want also to display the id of the image in a `TextView`, so how can i make a script that shows the image and the id at the same time, and how can i get the data into android apps.

this is how i get just the image from my `php` script:

```
 @Override
    protected ArrayList<Bitmap> doInBackground(String... params) {
        String phpurl = "http://192.168.1.11/save/load_image_from_db.php?id=3";
        URL url;
        Bitmap image = null;
            try {
                url = new URL(phpurl);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(connection.getInputStream());
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return image;
    }
```

Comment: don't you already have the ID of this image (`3`) in android? Why do you need another php script to tell you the ID that you already know?

Comment: What do you mean by ID of the image?

Comment: The id... it's on your url...

Comment: suppose that we have another column [NAME] and we want to retreive from mysql the name and the image of the given ID, i want to use the name and the Image in android apps; for example show image on imageView and change a TextView's text with the [NAME]

Comment: .. I've read that storing images in a db using a blob is not very peformant and is complicating things unneccesary. Better to store a jpg/png in a directory and just save the reference/link as text in db. A good idea would be to change the image filename, on upload, to the autoincrement ID from db + extension. This way a file named 1001.jpg  would be ID 1001. Picasso lib for android is good for loading image urls ...

Comment: I've also read that, do you know a good tutorial?